# troubleshoot legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I'm nearly there with my ggplot but want to do two more things:
a) change the name of the legend to "Animal" rather than "type" ("type" is the name of the column in the spreadsheet - as a last resort I guess I could just change that)
b) change the order of the categories in the legend, so they're the same as in the graph (total first, then cat, then dog)

```
raw_dat <- read.csv("./animals.csv")

ggplot(raw_dat, aes(x=years, y=number, color=type, group=type)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=low, ymax=high), width=.1) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(x=years,y=number,shape=type, color=type), size=2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("total" = "blue", "cat" = "red", "dog" = "green")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values= c("total" = 0, "cat" = 2, "dog" = 3))  +
  labs(name="Animal", shape = "type", color = "type") +
  xlab("Time (years)") +
  ylab("Number") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:350*50) +   
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:16*1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set the legend title inside labs via `shape = "Animal"` and `color = "Animal"`. One option to change the order of the legend entries is by setting the `limits` of both scales in your desired order:

```r
raw_dat <- data.frame(
  type = rep(c("dog", "cat", "total"), each = 15),
  years = 1:15,
  number = 1:15 + rep(c(2, 4, 6), each = 15)
)
raw_dat$low <- raw_dat$number - .5
raw_dat$high <- raw_dat$number + .5

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(raw_dat, aes(x=years, y=number, color=type, group=type)) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=low, ymax=high), width=.1) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(x=years,y=number,shape=type, color=type), size=2) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("total" = "blue", "cat" = "red", "dog" = "green"),  limits = c("total", "cat", "dog")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values= c("total" = 0, "cat" = 2, "dog" = 3),  limits = c("total", "cat", "dog"))  +
  labs(shape = "Animal", color = "Animal") +
  xlab("Time (years)") +
  ylab("Number") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:350*50) +   
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:16*1) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]